# Scratch not looping

Tags: loops, mit-scratch

I would like several sprites to move from left to right on a loop and start at different time.

Although I have used the "forever" control feature, it's not working. the sprites (baseball and basketball) stop at the right edge of the screen. In this specific case, I'm trying to put together a baseball challenge where the the player has to move the Batter up and down the screen and hit only the baseball not the basketball or any other distractor coming from the left side of the screen. https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/882521422/

Comment: The basketball has no `if touching edge` code to wrap it back to the left-hand side of the stage, so it keeps going to the right, stopping only at Scratch's own demand to keep at least 30 pixels visible. The baseball _does_ have that code, but it prevents the ball from entering the stage because 'touching edge' also applies to the _left_ edge. Besides, you made the baseball invisible. I suggest you play around a bit longer to get a better understanding of Scratch's mechanics.

Comment: That was very helpful. Thanks a lot. I added a line on the right side of the screen so that I could specify "if touching line", which solved the problem. Everything was working fine until I added the "Win" block and since then, the whole thing has not been working anymore.

Comment: Well done, your game works fine. You just need to `show` the basketball as well as the baseball `when green flag clicked`. Do not assume the project will automagically initialize your sprite's position/direction/visibility; always do so yourself. If you need any more support on this project, then please refer to the ["Help with scripts" forum](https://scratch.mit.edu/discuss/7/); Stack Overflow is not a collaborative coding platform.